# get the author name in recent post wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i want to display the the name of the author in my recent blog post . i tried this but not working. somebody please help me.

```
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '8' );
  $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){?>
         <i><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></i> 
         <i><?php echo $recent['post_author']; ?></i> 
}?>
```

`get_the_author();` it doesnt shows any output. And
`$recent['post_author'];` it shows output as 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_the_author()` won't work outside the post loop therefore isn't appropriate for use with `wp_get_recent_posts()`.

Your second version, `$recent['post_author']`, is outputting the correct value. You're seeing `1` because it's the author's ID rather than their name. You need to take the ID and use it to retrieve their name.

Use `the_author_meta()` to output the display name value:

```
<?php the_author_meta( 'display_name', $recent['post_author'] ); ?>
```